# How to resolve this Azure Event Grid Subscription error?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to create a subscription for my Azure EventGrid Topic using the Azure CLI command as below -

```
az eventgrid topic event-subscription create -g myresname --topic-name mytopicname --name mysubscriptionname --endpoint https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/mywebhookdetails
```

I am getting this error in the BASH shell in Azure CLI

```
az eventgrid topic: error: argument _subcommand: invalid choice: event-subscription
```

What is the reason and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There was a CLI update last month which introduced some changes in this syntax. Please use the following command (the only difference is you don't need to specify the "topic" after eventgrid):

az eventgrid event-subscription create -g myresname --topic-name mytopicname --name mysubscriptionname --endpoint https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/mywebhookdetails

Answer (score 1):

This is because the command you used `az eventgrid topic event-subscription create` is not for the latest version Azure CLI.

You can use this command in Azure CLI:

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create --endpoint
                                       --name
                                       [--endpoint-type {eventhub, webhook}]
                                       [--included-event-types]
                                       [--labels]
                                       [--resource-group]
                                       [--resource-id]
                                       [--subject-begins-with]
                                       [--subject-case-sensitive {false, true}]
                                       [--subject-ends-with]
                                       [--topic-name]
```

**Example:**

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create -g myresname --topic-name mytopicname --name mysubscriptionname --endpoint https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/mywebhookdetails
```

You can see more details in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az_eventgrid_event_subscription_create).

Comment: Hi, @GilliVilla How about your issue? Is this answer helpful ?